# Too slow booting in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, lenovo

I have just single-booted Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo G50-70. But now it boots slower than it used to when it was dual-booted with Windows. It reaches the purple blank page and hangs in it for a while.

The MCE log is as follows:

```
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0  
CPU 0 BANK 6   
MISC 1f8a0000086 ADDR fef87380   
TIME 1487630863 Tue Feb 21 00:47:43 2017  
MCG status:  
MCi status:  
Uncorrected error  
MCi_MISC register valid  
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt  
MCA: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region)  
Generic CACHE Level-2 Generic Error  
STATUS ae0000000040110a MCGSTATUS 0  
MCGCAP c07 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0   
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 69
```

**Update:**

The result of `systemd-analyze blame` is the following:

```
      10.324s dev-sda2.device   
      2.868s grub-common.service  
      2.759s ModemManager.service  
      2.272s accounts-daemon.service  
      2.173s apparmor.service  
      2.099s NetworkManager.service  
      1.939s thermald.service  
      1.935s plymouth-read-write.service  
      1.742s systemd-udevd.service  
      1.500s udisks2.service  
      1.434s plymouth-start.service  
      1.335s systemd-modules-load.service  
      1.241s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service  
      1.177s polkitd.service  
      1.133s lightdm.service  
      1.032s systemd-journald.service  
       896ms keyboard-setup.service  
       893ms gpu-manager.service    
       818ms apport.service  
       752ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service  
       720ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D0DB\x2d6E23.service  
       702ms kmod-static-nodes.service  
       581ms wpa_supplicant.service  
       523ms systemd-rfkill.service  
       511ms console-setup.service  
       476ms networking.service  
       406ms rsyslog.service  
       359ms systemd-logind.service    
       324ms dev-hugepages.mount  
       323ms sys-kernel-debug.mount  
       322ms dev-mqueue.mount  
       298ms ufw.service  
       291ms systemd-sysctl.service  
       256ms colord.service  
       232ms upower.service  
       228ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
       203ms systemd-udev-trigger.service  
       200ms snapd.refresh.service  
       151ms systemd-update-utmp.service  
       139ms bluetooth.service  
       127ms avahi-daemon.service  
       125ms systemd-remount-fs.service  
       106ms systemd-journal-flush.service  
        92ms systemd-timesyncd.service  
        91ms systemd-random-seed.service  
        88ms irqbalance.service  
        86ms dev-sda3.swap  
        75ms setvtrgb.service  
        73ms rtkit-daemon.service  
        55ms mcelog.service  
        52ms ondemand.service  
        50ms boot-efi.mount  
        44ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service  
        37ms speech-dispatcher.service  
        33ms snapd.socket  
        32ms user@1000.service  
        13ms systemd-user-sessions.service  
        11ms alsa-restore.service  
         5ms dns-clean.service  
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount  
         4ms ureadahead-stop.service  
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service  
         3ms pppd-dns.service  
         3ms resolvconf.service  
         1ms rc-local.service  
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

Comment: How many seconds / minutes = "a while"? Also try `systemd-analyze blame` and post results in your question if you feel they are appropriate.

Comment: A few minutes. Too slow for a Core i7 device I guess.

Comment: I've added the result of `systemd-analyze blame` in the question.

Comment: It's been a few months now. Have you made any progress with your slow boot speed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's trying to mount the Windows partition but fails.

If that's the case you should configure it not to try to mount the Windows partition in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really that, but does opening /etc/fstab using the file manager or typing `cat /etc/fstab` in a terminal show a Windows-related mount point?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing but the errors look like chip errors, possibly in the CPU or RAM. Checking that your RAM is plugged in properly may be a good start. A memory cache error may be to do with the CPU, as some CPUs have a small amount of onboard memory. The clue is the topline - hardware error - this is not a software error, so if you have access the the inside of your computer, check connections are all as they should be. In low level computing, MC may refer to the Memory Controller, which assigns address spaces. I would thouroughly check the RAM you have plugged in.

Comment: I have had my laptop for 3 years now and I never really touched the RAM. This problem started happening when I had a fresh installation of Ubuntu a few months ago. Does checking the RAM need hardware expertise or is there some way I can do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

memtest86 ver 5.01 ought to be in your boot menu - checks ram; just went through that - If it's not on your boot menu; get the configure grub app and then add memtest.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The text that you have added would be classed more of a follow on statement, not an answer. Next time please add this as a comment.